# .NET Profiler enter/leave function hooks not called

Tags: .net, clr-profiling-api

I want to use a .NET profiler to trace the called functions of an application. I used [CLR Profiler](http://clrprofiler.codeplex.com/) as a template, but didn't change the profiler (Project `ProfilerOBJ`) itself (except the GUID). When I try to profile an application the enter/leave function hooks (besides other callbacks like `JITCompilationStarted`) are **not** called. But there are also some callbacks which are called (e.g. `Shutdown`) (which tells me that the profiler is loaded in the process).

I tried running the processes in 32 and 64 bit (with 64 bit the function hooks seem to be defined somewhere) without success.

The test application I profiled is as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to allocate object");
        Console.ReadLine();
        var obj = new Person();

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to call method on allocated object");
        Console.ReadLine();
        obj.Walk();

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Person
{
    private int walked = 0;

    public void Walk()
    {
        this.walked++;
    }
}
```

I expected at least the callbacks `ICorProfilerCallback::ObjectAllocated` and the enter/leave function hooks to be called. But the only callback called was `ICorProfilerCallback::Shutdown`.

It seems that even the original CLR profiler's enter/leave function hooks are not called (I tried to output a message in the callback).

What am I missing? Is there more to do than registering the enter/leave function hooks? Or am I making wrong assumptions about the enter/leave function hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just [read](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2007/03/22/enter-leave-tailcall-hooks-part-1-basics.aspx) that there are additional flags you may set to specify in which events you are interested. One of them is `COR_PRF_MONITOR_ENTERLEAVE` which does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks [rubberduck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).